# How to implement Proptypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am new to react so be kind :)

Simply trying to get prop types to validate. I am not seeing any errors in the console. I have spent a good amount of time and can't seem to get past this. Any assistance would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { MdTerrain } from 'react-icons/md/'
import { TiWeatherSnow } from 'react-icons/ti/'
import { FaCalendar } from 'react-icons/fa/'
import '../stylesheets/ui.scss'



const percentToDecimal = (decimal) => {
    return((decimal * 100) + '%')
}

const calcGoalProgress = (total, goal) => {
    return percentToDecimal(total/goal)
}




export const SkiDayCount = ({total, powder, backcountry, goal}) =>  (
    <div className="ski-day-count">
        <div className="total-days">
            <span>{total}</span>
            <FaCalendar />
            <span>days</span>
        </div>
        <div className="powder-days">
            <span>{powder}</span>
            <TiWeatherSnow />
            <span>days</span>
        </div>
        <div className="backcountry-days">
            <span>{backcountry}</span>
            <MdTerrain />
            <span>days</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>{calcGoalProgress(total, goal)}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
)


SkiDayCount.defaultProps = {
    total:'sdf',
    powder:10,
    backcountry:15,
    goal:75
}

SkiDayCount.propTypes = {
    total: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    powder: PropTypes.number,
    backcountry: PropTypes.number
}
```

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: Console is blank. There are no errors and the proptype SHOULD be generating an error.

Comment: The prop `total` is marked as required in `SkiDayCount` and also you marked defaultProps total:'sdf' so it won't show you any warning in console. Please check this demo for clarity https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j1bdnr

Comment: Jayavel - 'sdf' is a string and I have the prototype set to number - shouldn't that throw an error?

Comment: I have forked Jayavel link to https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q7anse?file=index.js and I can see all the validation errors

Answer (score 0):

have you check that you are in development mode.For performance reasons, propTypes is only checked in development mode.[Check here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Comment: Yes - I am in dev mode.